# Where-Object must meet exact criteria -and statement seems to be working as or

Tags: powershell, filter

I could be making a basic mistake and I've been through nearly every article online but this is driving me nuts. I am using where-object to get the objects which must meet the criteria explicitly.

data set

```
mail                 department version
tuser1@tdomain.com   finance        1.0
tuser2@tdomain.com   finance        1.1
tuser3@tdomain.com   hr             2.0
tuser4@tdomain.com   hr             1.1
tuser5@tdomain.com   hr             1.0
tuser6@tdomain.com   finance        1.1
tuser7@tdomain.com   finance        2.0
```

I have a large dataset which I want to export a subset of users by eliminating certain criterias. This is only one but there will be more if I can get it working.

So far I have tried

```
$Data | select-object mail, department, version |  Where-Object {$_.Department -ne 'Finance' -and $_.version -ne '1.0'}

$Data | select-object mail, department, version |  Where-Object {($_.Department -ne 'Finance') -and ($_.version -ne '1.0')}

$Data | select-object mail, department, version |  Where-Object {($_.Department -ne 'Finance' -and $_.version -ne '1.0')}
```

This should be straight forward from what I read but it is behaving strange. What I am finding is that the -AND function is almost working like an -OR function. If I run any of the above it is not performing the filter on both objects as one. What I find it is not selecting any users with the department not equals finance (correct, this is what I want) or any users with version not equals 1.0 (incorrect, surely it should still select HR users version 1.0?). I assume the whole point of the -AND function is that both arguements need to match? Unless I am mistaken?

Like I said I could be doing something very silly but I have looked quite a bit online and I can't seem to find anything which would suggest I am doing anything wrong here. I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: your data set does NOT show `givenName`, `Company`, or `mail`. [*grin*] so ... how are those fields getting into your data?

Comment: also, PLEASE, wrap your code in code formatting. right now, things like underscores are being consumed by the text formatting [they toggle italic mode].

Comment: Hi Lee that is an example. The data set I posted is what the filter is concentrated on. I didn’t think there would be much point posting additional data. I will update the code I was wondering why that has commented out.

Comment: I put triple backquotes around the code.  For some reasons the underlines don't show otherwise.

Comment: Code should be updated now

Comment: @MavCoder - please, make sure your code AND your data match up. one cannot reliably parse code that does things that CANNOT be done with the data you say is there to work with.

Comment: post updated to reflect dataset to match code

Comment: It works for me.  Are both properties strings?  It's not just a plain text file is it?

Comment: I'd guess that it's a _design_ or _logic_ issue rather than a _powershell_ one. Your code returns `tuser3` and `tuser4` ( i.e. excludes **both** `finance` *and*  `1.0`).

Comment: @MavCoder - thank you for fixing the date/code disconnect! [*grin*] ///// your code works as written. `tuser3` and `tuser4` are the only ones who DO NOT match _both_ `finance` and `1.0`. negatives are easy [very easy] to get confused about. you are likely going to be happier with a positive test and then negating that OR using the `-or` for your test. it looks like `js2010` has demoed those quite neatly. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is a logic problem.  Maybe in the question put the result you want.  Excluding lines that have both "finance" and "1.0".  Because of operator precedence, the parentheses are required.

```
import-csv file.csv | 
where {-not ($_.Department -eq 'Finance' -and $_.version -eq '1.0')}

department version
---------- -------
finance    1.1
hr         2.0
hr         1.1
hr         1.0
finance    1.1
finance    2.0
```

This is actually logically equivalent to "-or" not "-and".  I think the first way is less confusing.

```
import-csv file.csv | 
where {$_.Department -ne 'Finance' -or $_.version -ne '1.0'}

department version
---------- -------
finance    1.1
hr         2.0
hr         1.1
hr         1.0
finance    1.1
finance    2.0
```